# Read pygame window with open cv

Tags: python, opencv, pygame, object-detection

I am very new to python and I am working on a project using pygame and cv2

My first python file code has an output image that shows up in a pygame window, but I have another python file that detects objects and it gets an input video like this:

`cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")`

and then it reads the video and shows the detected objects in the video by surrounding boxes around each object.

I want the `cap = cv2.VideoCapture()` to get the live video from the pygame window and maybe show the boxes of object detection in a second window or the same pygame window (not sure right now what I want, but maybe showing it in the same pygame window would be better)

I am not sure if this is enough information to help me since I am not very familiar with pygame or cv2, please let me know.

Comment: You can use `PIL.ImageGrab` to grab your screen, then use `cv2.cvtColor` to convert it into OpenCV form.  And by the way, it was 60 seconds with Google to find those examples.

Answer (score 0):

In pygame you are actually drawing on a [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) object. You can get the [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object associated with the display with [`pygame.display.get_surface()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.get_surface):

```py
screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
```

Use [`pygame.surfarray.pixels3d`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.pixels3dv) to create a new 3D array that directly references the pixel values in the *Surface*. This is equivalent to a *cv2* matrix respectively [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) array when you transpose the *x* and *y* axis and transform from RGB to BGR:

```py
capture = pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(screen)
capture = capture.transpose([1, 0, 2])
capture_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(capture, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

Do this once per frame after updating the display:

```py
def capture_frame():
    screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
    capture = pygame.surfarray.pixels3d(screen)
    capture = capture.transpose([1, 0, 2])
    capture_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(capture, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    return capture_bgr

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    # draw
    # [...]

    pygame.display.flip()
    
    frame_img = capture_frame()    
    # [...]
```